# How to replace tags with jquery?

Tags: jquery, html, dom

I have a question, I want to replace the following code

```
<h2> Heading 1</h2>
<h2> Heading 2</h2>
```

with the following code

```
<h2><span> Heading 1</span></h2>
<h2><span> Heading 2</span></h2>
```

I want to do that with jquery. Please help me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use

```
$('h2').wrapInner('<span/>')
```

Answer (score 6):

Try using `wrapInner`.

`$('h2').wrapInner('<span/>')`

Comment: >.< I got down voted :P . To Down voter, to cancel up vote, I think you need click on up vote again (which is basically undo up vote). Down vote will not negate your up vote.

Answer (score 2):

Please take some time to review the [jQuery api](http://api.jquery.com/). [`wrapInner`](http://api.jquery.com/wrapinner) will do the trick.

```
$('h2').wrapInner('<span>');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using [$.wrapInner](http://api.jquery.com/wrapInner/)

```
$('h2').wrapInner('<span/>')
```

Comment: Joy, thank you, this work, but how to make it automatic? If I follow your tutorial, I must make it one by one

Comment: It will add `<span>` in all `<h2>` elements. Please clarify if you want otherwise.